# How to calculating date value in XSL...?

Tags: xml

I am pretty new to XSLT/XML...trying to do XSL transformation with date calculation, however I get no result when I tested it using XSLT online tool e.g. http://www.xsltcake.com/

This is XML:

`<record>`
`<field name="Identifier">00000ZG7</field>`
`<field name="ContestNumber">00000ZG7</field>`
`<field name="CareerSiteNo3">spool</field>`
`<field name="OpeningDate">2012-05-14</field>`
`<field name="EndDate">2012-05-14T10:05:00-04:00</field>`
`<field name="HotJobFlag">false</field>`
`</record>`

This is XSLT:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://www.abc.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:fct="http://www.abc.com/xsl_functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`
    `<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>`
    `<xsl:param name="delimiter">,</xsl:param>`
    `<xsl:template match="ns:record">`
        `<xsl:value-of select="ns:field[@name='Identifier']"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="ns:field[@name='ContestNumber']"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="ns:field[@name='CareerSiteNo3']"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="ns:field[@name='OpeningDate']"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>`
        `<xsl:variable name="End2Days" select="ns:field[@name='EndDate']"/>`
        `<xsl:choose>`
            `<xsl:when test="ns:field[@name='CareerSiteNo3']='spool'">`
                `<xsl:value-of select="(xs:date($End2Days)+((xs:dayTimeDuration('P2D'))"/>`
            `</xsl:when>`
            `<xsl:otherwise>`
                `<xsl:value-of select="(xs:date($End2Days)+((xs:dayTimeDuration('P14D'))"/>`
            `</xsl:otherwise>`
        `</xsl:choose>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>`
        `<xsl:value-of select="ns:field[@name='HotJobFlag']"/>`
        `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>`
    `</xsl:template>`
`</xsl:stylesheet>`

If I take out the part `<xsl:choose>`, I can get a line of the result. However if I include the choose node, I get no result.Basically what I want to do is when "CareerSiteNo3" is "spool", just add 2 days from End Date value, otherwise add 14 days.

Please advise me what I am doing wrong....thanks so much.

Comment: the `xsl:value-of` (both of them) within the `choose` are missing `))` at the end. your input XML is also missing the namespace declaration. The `record` likely looks like `<record xmlns="http://www.abc.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">`. Is that right? then, when I run it with the correction I just recommended, it (Saxon HE) reports `FORG0001: Invalid date "2012-05-14T10:05:00-04:00" (Day must be two digits)`. Maybe your online tool swallows the errors ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using XSLT 2.0 features in your code; are you sure that the online testing tool you tried supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I used a different online testing tool which definitely supports XSLT2.0 and it worked after all... :D Thanks